# How do I extract tweets that mentions a specific word and/or phrase from the text?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, twitter, text-extraction

So I want to know what people are saying about KFC, Popeyes, and ChickfilA's chicken sandwiches for a project. NOTE: I already have all the Twitter data I need.

I successfully extracted users and their screennames but have yet to figure out how to go a step further and figure out who mentioned 'sandwich' in their tweet.

I am pretty sure what this code is doing is extracting all users whose tweets are exactly 'sandwich'... I cannot figure out how to extract tweets where sandwich is just MENTIONED. I have researched and think i can do this task with the re.findall() or with the Tweepy library? Can anybody show me exactly what I need to do?

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
uniqueusers = {}

keyword = 'sandwich'

for tweetzipfile in tweetzipfiles:
  zf = zipfile.ZipFile(tweetzipfile)
  for i, obj in enumerate(zf.infolist()):
    tweetjson = json.load(zf.open(obj))
    userwhotweeted = tweetjson['user']['screen_name']
    tweettext = tweetjson['text']
    if tweettext == keyword:
      if userwhotweeted in uniqueusers:
        uniqueusers[userwhotweeted] += 1
      if userwhotweeted not in uniqueusers:
        uniqueusers[userwhotweeted] = 1
```

Comment: change `if tweettext == keyword:` to  `if keyword in tweettext:`

Answer (score 0):

I would need more than that to test, but if you are looking for the hiccup, it's because you are searched for tweettext to equal the single word. That's why it is returning such.

You would need to do something like:

```
    if keyword in tweettext:
      if userwhotweeted in uniqueusers:
        uniqueusers[userwhotweeted] += 1
      elif userwhotweeted not in uniqueusers:
        uniqueusers[userwhotweeted] = 1
    else:
      print("No Results")
```

Something to that extent.

You can also use a variation of this with `.split()` if you want to turn a block of text from the tweet into individual items in a list.

It will make it easier to work with the keywords.